# Get error line number and file name from which the class call was made

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a class for handling errors.

I would like to call a public static method of the class to log the errors my RPC server is throwing at me without the need to use the `__LINE__` comand.

Something like this:

```
class errorHander{
    public static $errors = array();
    public static function logError($message){
        self::$errors[] = array('message', NEEED SOMHOW TO GET THE calling class, get the file in which the error ocured);
    }
}
```

And this is most important, without passing the file location from the called function.

So something like `errorHander:logError(message, location)` is a no go.

Comment: What kind of errors you get? exceptions? or RPC server returns some error response?

Answer (score 1):

Exception::getLine and getFile methods, I donot way a way to do this without handling Exceptions.
Heres a reference.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: this class dous somthing similar, but i need to know the class which called the error class without changing the code in the class which called the error.

Comment: the getTrace does that, but really why can't you edit the class that calls error??

Answer (score 0):

Well this obviously depends on what kind of error you have.

You might want to look at exception handling. PHPs exception class offers the methods getLine() and getTrace(). This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: i ma trowing a nrmal error in php, but the server is handling rpc.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you want to express with that.

Answer (score 0):

logError() need only one parameter not 2.

do something like this:

```
 class errorHander{
        public static $errors = array();
        public static function logError($message){
            self::$errors[] = array('message'=>$message);
        }
    }


    errorHander:logError("This is a no-yes go") //This should log

    echo errorHander:errors[0]["message"]; //print it
```

hope it helps

Comment: This is how the current system works. i want to figure out the name of the class which called the static method.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the xdebug-extension: http://xdebug.org

You may use `xdebug_call_file()` and `xdebug_call_class()` to get the information you need.

See the documentation: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions